Is it possible to capture all audio output on an iOS device using private APIs and distribute the app through alternative App Stores in the EU?
I'm currently investigating the feasibility of developing an iOS app for a client that needs to capture all audio output from the device before it reaches the headphones or speakers. Think of it as an audio processor.
I understand that capturing all audio using the standard iOS API is not possible due to Apple's sandboxing restrictions and ethical considerations. Jailbreaking the device is one possible solution, but it is not a viable option for targeting a large audience.
Given that we are based in the EU, I am exploring the possibility of using alternative App Stores that do not have the same strict review process as the official Apple App Store. My questions are:

Is it technically possible to capture all audio output using private APIs on a non-jailbroken device?
If we distribute the app through alternative App Stores in the EU, can we use private APIs to achieve this functionality?

Any insights or alternative suggestions for capturing audio output on iOS devices would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

this is probably ages later, but I figured out a way to get the audio from certain apps. Did you figure out a way using some private API to get all system audio?

To distribute your app via an alternative App Store you must still submit your app to Apple for review and notarisation. A subset of the App Store Review Guidelines applies. - You can see which guidelines apply by checking the Show Notarization Review Guidelines Only checkbox on that page.
If you do so, you will see that clause 2.5.1 still applies:

Apps may only use public APIs and must run on the currently shipping OS. Learn more about public APIs...

So, the short answer is, no, using an alternative App Store will not allow you to use private APIs
